# Benefit of initializing dictionary in function call

Tags: python, dictionary

I was looking at this code on the Google Map API website:

```
import simplejson, urllib
GEOCODE_BASE_URL = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json'

def geocode(address,sensor, **geo_args):
    geo_args.update({
        'address': address,
        'sensor': sensor  
    })

    url = GEOCODE_BASE_URL + '?' + urllib.urlencode(geo_args)
    result = simplejson.load(urllib.urlopen(url))

    print simplejson.dumps([s['formatted_address'] for s in result['results']], indent=2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    geocode(address="San+Francisco",sensor="false")
```

I noticed that in the geocode function, when we actually apply the function we don't use the geo_args dictionary when we call the function, but we instead use it to initialize a dictionary we update in the next lines. What is the benefit of using this, as opposed to initializing the dictionary within the function itself? It makes the code a bit less clear so I assume there is a reason for doing it.

Comment: It just a way to combine the two non-keyword arguments with the ones already in `geo_args` which is passed to `urllib.urlencode()`. Could be done other ways -- how it's done doesn't seem too significant to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`geo_args` is used. The literal dictionary

```
{
    'address': address,
    'sensor': sensor  
}
```

updates `geo_args`, not the other way around.

The reason it's like this looks to me that `address` and `sensor` are required arguments. This structure allows the function to enforce that requireness, and also allow them to be passed positionally. The `.update()` is just there to consolidate all the arguments into one so they can be given to `urllib.urlencode`.

Comment: Why not start the dictionary within the geocode defintion though, i.e. geo_args={}?

Comment: @Andrew: isn't that the code from the question? I'm not sure what you are trying to tell me. Maybe you are simply confused about [kwargs](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/)?

Comment: Nah not confused about kwargs. I am saying why use def geocode(address,sensor, **geo_args): instead of def geocode(address,sensor): geo_args={} for the first line

Comment: @Andrew: because then it would be a totally different function. You couldn't do, for example, `geocode(someaddres, somesensor, somethingelse="foobar")`. It sounds like you are definitely confused about kwargs.

Comment: Looking at the example utilization of the function, they do not use the additional arguments that would provide. So is the only benefit of doing this to provide the option to add those arguments?

Comment: @Andrew: yes, exactly. Since this is used to construct a URL, this allows you to add arbitrary query-string arguments to the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear? This is the normal behaviour of **kwargs (the keyword argument dictionary).
So when you see something with `**`, a bunch of named parameters or keyword arguments will be passed.

Seeing the other answers. I probably misunderstood your question. I agree with the other answers: address and sensor are required.